# Trying to learn Mysql and run into a foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed error

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, foreign-keys, create-table

For some reason my code won't let me create the projects table due to the foreign key error. I have tried a few different things and just cant seem to get it to work, ive tried looking on here for solutions but cant seem to do it. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
CREATE TABLE PEOPLE (
    NAME VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    GENDER ENUM('Male', 'Female', 'Other'),
    DOB DATE NOT NULL,
    SALARY VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
    PROJECT VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    BUSINESS_NAME VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(NAME, PROJECT)
);

CREATE TABLE PEOPLE_EMAILS (
    NAME_ID VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    EMAIL VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(EMAIL),
    FOREIGN KEY(NAME_ID) REFERENCES PEOPLE(NAME)
);

CREATE TABLE PEOPLE_PHONE (
    NAME_ID2 VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    PHONE_NUMBER VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (PHONE_NUMBER),
    FOREIGN KEY(NAME_ID2) REFERENCES PEOPLE(NAME)
);

CREATE TABLE PROJECTS (
    PROJECT_NAME VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    PROJECT_LOCATION VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    BUDGET VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY(PROJECT_NAME) REFERENCES PEOPLE(PROJECT)
);
```

Comment: `FOREIGN KEY(PROJECT_NAME) REFERENCES PEOPLE(PROJECT)` - it is necessary that there should be an index in `PEOPLE` table which' expression is equal or starts from the `PROJECT` field. Now there is no such index.

Comment: The simplest solution in your case is `CREATE INDEX idx_project ON people (project);`.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, you want the foreign key the other way around. You would expect people to reference projects instead of projects to reference people.

This means that you need to create the projects table first, and then the people table. Also, you need a proper primary key on projects so you can reference it in people (I assumed `project_name`).

```
CREATE TABLE PROJECTS (
    PROJECT_NAME VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    PROJECT_LOCATION VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    BUDGET VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (PROJECT_NAME)
);

CREATE TABLE PEOPLE (
    NAME VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    GENDER ENUM('Male', 'Female', 'Other'),
    DOB DATE NOT NULL,
    SALARY VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
    PROJECT VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    BUSINESS_NAME VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(NAME, PROJECT),
    FOREIGN KEY(PROJECT) REFERENCES PROJECTS(PROJECT_NAME)
);

CREATE TABLE PEOPLE_EMAILS (
    NAME_ID VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    EMAIL VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(EMAIL),
    FOREIGN KEY(NAME_ID) REFERENCES PEOPLE(NAME)
);

CREATE TABLE PEOPLE_PHONE (
    NAME_ID2 VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    PHONE_NUMBER VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (PHONE_NUMBER),
    FOREIGN KEY(NAME_ID2) REFERENCES PEOPLE(NAME)
);
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=cb708aeefc0cc444402f6bbc8338cdb9)**